# how to save activity's state in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know how can I save state of a page(Activity) so when I come back to that page it should be in state in which I left it.
 for eg if I checked a checkbox in page so after leaving that page when I come back that checkbox should be checked as I left.
thanks in advance

Comment: I think this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/

Take a look at this tutorial about `SharedPreferences`

or

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a case where another Activity interrupts the current one then you should look into managing the Activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle
onSaveInstanceState(), onRestoreInstanceState() or in onPause() and onResume().

If this is for persistent data storage then SharedPreferences / DB or some other form of storage would be required: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html